# Undocumented method to find sim card availability in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7

I have found an undocumented method for detecting sim card availability in iphone. This method needs CoreTelephony.framework

```
NSString * CTSIMSupportGetSIMStatus();
int CTGetSignalStrength();

NSString *status = CTSIMSupportGetSIMStatus();

NSLog(@"Sim card status %@",status);
```

This method works well. can i use this method in my project? If i use this undocumented method, will apple reject my app? plz let me know... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use undocumented method as Apple says that they can change the implementation for bug fixing or by updating the SDK cause App crash. They do not allow the use of Private API and trace at submission at store. Mostly private method can be found in debugging at Xcode and start with _Underscore so you can try alternative to achieving things if you do not want to get reject your application later at submission.