# Private api CTGetSignalStrength() not working on Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, bridging-header, xcode7.3, swift2

```
NSString * CTSIMSupportGetSIMStatus();
int CTGetSignalStrength();
```

giving compilation error on xcode 7.3 using bridging header in swift, it was working fine on previous versions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779785/undocumented-method-to-find-sim-card-availability-in-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define your own objective-c method like

```
+ (int)getSignalStrength {
     return CTGetSignalStrength();
}
```

and call c style method there, as in xcode7.3 c-style methods in objective-c class not calling.